# Label Reshaping for CNN

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras, conv-neural-network

I am facing problem while reshaping the data to fit in Convolutional Neural Network. I've tried many solutions but still unable to do that. Dataset Contains 800 rows and 271 columns (last column contains class label). There are total 9 classes. Below is my Code:

```
 dataset = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

 X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:270].values
 y = dataset.iloc[:, 270].values

 print("X Shape: "+str(X.shape))  ---> (804, 270)

 *** Reshaping Variables here

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_reshaped, Y_reshaped, test_size = 0.20)

 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Convolution1D(64, kernel_size=(10), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(100))
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Dense(9))
 model.add(Activation('softmax'))
 model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
 model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
 print(str(model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)))
```

Is there anyway to successfully reshape the variables for training the model? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convolution1D requires an input of the form

```
(samples, steps, input_dim)
```

Right now you are passing

```
(samples,input_dim)
```

You need to reshape the data depending on how you have arranged the timesteps in the 800 rows.

For example, if the 800 rows are 80 samples of 10 timesteps, like 10 timesteps of first sample followed by 10 of another...

 then you need to reshape is as (80,10,270)

Answer (score 0):

The Convolutional1D is for processing temporal data and you do not seem to have it. You need to split your data into number of samples and timesteps